# Como redirecionar no primeiro acesso outra página invés da index?

Tags: htaccess

Acho que é mais fácil de entender assim: Quando eu digitar meu domínio:

> www.site.com.br

Geralmente vai pra index.php

Mas eu não quero que vá para index e sim para inicio.php

Como seria um regra htacess para isso?

Answer (score 2):

Segue o exemplo

```
DirectoryIndex inicio.php
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Rafael Augusto

Comment: @userJohnNotSoDoeGrey marque a resposta como resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando Apache, abra o arquivo httpd.conf e altere a linha DirectoryIndex para:

```
DirectoryIndex  inicio.html index.html index.htm
```

Desta forma, o arquivo padrão que o Apache irá buscar será inicio.html.
Se este arquivo não existir, então ele irá procurar por um arquivo chamado index.html (o padrão), e assim por diante.
Caso não encontre nenhum arquivo, irá listar o conteúdo do diretório caso isso seja permitido.